# Calling Twitter API from Postman works, but from Angular 2 app it doesnt'

Tags: http, twitter, angular, cors, postman

I am trying to use Twitter API in my app.

When I run it from Postman, it works great.

[image: Postman]

However, when I run it from my app, using Google Chrome I get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=canada. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Here is my code for it

```
...

     getTweets(hashtag : string){
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAONruQAAAAAAfxQda4njz64axXN9sw4U0oU%3Dr1niTwKwXoOZXmZczDKgN0wWHWEMPrPcnXXMgVQhiTIzays7J');
        var requestOptions = new MyRequest();
        requestOptions.headers = headers;

      return this.http.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=montreal', requestOptions);  
    }
}

class MyRequest implements RequestOptionsArgs {
    public headers: Headers;
}
```

Comment: You have not added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your headers.  The error is clearly telling you that it's required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API doesn't support CORS but JSONP. So you need the leverage the JSONP support of Angular2.

Here is à sample. First specify the corresponding providers when bootstrapping your application:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ JSONP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

Then inject the Jsonp class (instead of the Http one) and use it to make your request:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(jsonp:Jsonp) {
    var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=montreal&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK';

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer AAAAAAAA(...)sw4U0oU%');

    jsonp.request(url, { method: 'Get', headers: headers })
     .subscribe((res) => {
       this.result = res.json()
     });
```

See rhis question for more details:

- [I need to do a http request to a mail chimp subscription list via a component post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180562/i-need-to-do-a-http-request-to-a-mail-chimp-subscription-list-via-a-component-po/35181085)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this isn't working. I get a 400 or 401 error, and when I look in devtools I don't even see Authorization as one of the headers, so I fear the syntax for adding the headers is not correct

Comment: I just read this in the doc regarding the callback parameter: "If supplied, the response will use the JSONP format with a callback of the given name. The usefulness of this parameter is somewhat diminished by the requirement of authentication for requests to this endpoint.". See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets.

Comment: Do you import the `Headers` class? `import {Http, Headers, ...} from 'angular2/http'`. Without it in the imports, the headers aren't sent and there is no error message...

Comment: Yes, you're right! We can send headers since jsonp relies on the adding of a script tag in the HTML page...

Comment: We can or *can't*?

Comment: what good is accessing Twitter API via jsonp when you first have to authenticate your app?  Authentication through Twitter requires a POST and your cannot POST via jsonp.  How do you interact with Twitter API when Twitter API does not support CORS by setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in pre-flight OPTIONS?