# observable returning error, but request data comes back fine

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm getting an error with a reactive extension (rx) Observable subscribe operator and not seeing why. It seems that the same code in tutorials I've done works fine, but for some reason I'm getting an error working with an actual API.

```
getChannelVideos(channelId: string): Observable<any>{
  var url = `${this._baseUrl}/channels/${channelId}/videos`;

  return this._jsonp.get(url).map(response => response.json());
}

// url https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/khaldor/videos
```

In my component, I call that service function in `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this._twitchService.getChannelVideos('khaldor')
    .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
}
```

In the network tab, I get a 200 response with a JSON object

```
{"_total":2,
  "_links":{...}, 
  "videos": {...} 
}
```

In the console, I get an error `videos:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` which references the first semi-colon in the returned JSON response.

I've tried removing the `.map` in the service, but I get the same error when applying `.subscribe()` to the Observable object in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your address isn't JSONP-compliant. If it's the case, you need to provide the `JSONP_CALLBACK` value to the callback query parameter. Something like that:

```
getChannelVideos(channelId: string): Observable<any>{
  var url = `${this._baseUrl}/channels/${channelId}/videos?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;

  return this._jsonp.get(url).map(response => response.json());
}
```

The `callback` is a sample and depends on the service.

If your service supports CORS, you could leverage the `Http` class instead:

```
constructor(private http:Http) {}

getChannelVideos(channelId: string): Observable<any>{
  var url = `${this._baseUrl}/channels/${channelId}/videos`;

  return this.http.get(url).map(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: if it wasn't JSONP compliant would it be returning data? When I used the Http service it gave me the typical error when making CORS requests without CORS enabled. I switched to JSONP (they say it's compliant), and I get data back from the request, in the Network tab.

Comment: If the service is JSONP, that's fine. The problem is that you don't specify a callback name, so the response is simple JSON but not wrapped in a function call. Something like that: `callback([ { name: 'test' }, ... ]);`. Because JSONP relies on a dynamic script element added to execute the request, the response must follow this...

Comment: Here are two samples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289495/how-to-make-a-simple-jsonp-asynchronous-request-in-angular-2/36289568#36289568 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180562/i-need-to-do-a-http-request-to-a-mail-chimp-subscription-list-via-a-component-po/35181085#35181085.

Comment: You need to find out which query parameter to use to provide the callback name...

Comment: thanks, first time working with JSONP and that confused me. Now I see it in the docs.

Comment: No problem! It's actually not so obvious!